# Разделение ячеек в колонке на определенные группы исходя из текстового значения в другой колонке

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

Всем привет, есть задача, указать в пандасовской колонке[column 2] одно из значении ['Значение 1'], ['Значение 2'], ['Значение 3'] исходя из текстового значении в другой колонке [Колонка 1].
В [column 1] содержаться следующие значения [text 1], [text2],[text1],..., [text n].
Как сгруппировать тексты на группы по схожести (по словам).

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hGLBp3E1tIokr7O4A3wM_TyVoP9XreC2/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115758431869487453011&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Есть разница между простой группировкой и группировкой по схожести.

Comment: Я в примере указал простой случай. Можно ли сделать группировку по схожести?Через токенизацию слов, их векторизацию и расчета близости друг к другу каждой ячейки.

Comment: Ну так вы подготовьте токенизацию, лемматизацию или что там еще, запишите в соответствующую колонку для каждой строки, а дальше думать будем.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант - сделать так:

```
df["Column 2"] ="Значение " + df.groupby("Column 1").ngroup().astype(str)
```

df:

```
                                Column 1    Column 2
Row                                                 
1            Счет требовани¤ по кредитам  Значение 2
2              Счет требовани¤ по картам  Значение 1
3             Счет требовани¤ по вкладам  Значение 0
4               Счет требовани¤ по – РКО  Значение 4
5    Счет требовани¤ по кредитным картам  Значение 3
6            Счет требовани¤ по кредитам  Значение 2
7              Счет требовани¤ по картам  Значение 1
8             Счет требовани¤ по вкладам  Значение 0
9               Счет требовани¤ по – РКО  Значение 4
10   Счет требовани¤ по кредитным картам  Значение 3
```